# How to get USERID from accessdatabase

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a window in WPF. When I user enter name, I want to insert it to database and get USERID.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbDataReader rd;
            string name=comboBox1.Text;
            OleDbConnection conn=new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|CellBiology.mdb;Persist Security Info=

True");
            string sql = "select * from UserInformation where UserName='" + name+ "'";
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rd.Read())
            {

                string id = rd["UserID"].ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(id);


            }
            else
            {
                string sql2 = "insert into UserInformation(UserName) values ('" + ad+ "')";
                OleDbCommand ne = new OleDbCommand(sql2, conn);
                ne.ExecuteNonQuery();

**the problem is here.**


     }
```

Comment: It might help to both 1) say what the problem is (EG what the error message you are getting) and 2) tag the questions with whatever programming language you're using to build and run that SQL

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are never initializing the variable `ad` you are using in the following SQL:

```
string sql2 = "insert into UserInformation(UserName) values ('" + ad+ "')";
```

Which is a problem.